# How do I change my Batch Script to accept multiple files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

**How do I allow this script to run on multiple files?**

I have a script that takes a file and moves it to a specific directory.

```
move /-y %1 "E:\Folder\"
```

In order to accept multiple files in the script I changed  `%1` to `%*`.

When I `@echo %*` the output is:

```
c:\file one.mp4 c:\file two.mp4 c:\file three.mp4
```

When I use the code below no files are moved.

```
move /-y %* "E:\Folder\"
```

**What would you recommend I change in my script to allow all the files to be moved?**

Answer (score 2):

Please find the solution I used below.

```
for %%d in (%*) do (move /-y %%d "E:\Folder")
```